# MySQL JOIN with entry relations

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `foo` VARCHAR ( 32 ) NOT NULL,
  `bar` VARCHAR ( 32 ) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
);
```

Multiple objects can have certain relations to each other, which are listed in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `id1` INT NOT NULL,
  `id2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id1`, `id2` )
  FOREIGN KEY ( `id1`, `id2` ) REFERENCES `objects` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If two objects have a certain relation to each other, an entry is put into the `relations` table with `id1` being the id of the first object and `id2` being the id of the second object. Now I want to load the objects with their relations to other objects and store them in a Java object which looks as follows:

```
public class Obj {

  private final Set<Obj> relations = new HashSet<>();

  // ...

}
```

I am looking for a way to properly load in the relations with a JOIN, where it selects `id2` from all rows with a matching `id`/`id1` and `id1` from all rows with a matching `id`/`id2`.

I could use the following query:

```
SELECT `objects`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`relations`.`id1`) AS `id1`
FROM `objects`
LEFT JOIN `relations`
ON `objects`.`id` = `relations`.`id2`
GROUP BY `objects`.`id`;
```

However, this will only select give me the `id1`'s for any `relations` row with `id2` matching with `id`, but it will not give me the `id2`'s for the `relations` rows with `id1` matching with `id`.

Is it possible to somehow select them both ways?

Example: I have the following data entered in the tables:

```
INSERT INTO `objects` ( `foo`, `bar` ) VALUES ( 'hi', 'this' );
INSERT INTO `objects` ( `foo`, `bar` ) VALUES ( 'is', 'an' );
INSERT INTO `objects` ( `foo`, `bar` ) VALUES ( 'example', 'row' );
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ( 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ( 3, 1 );
```

When I now select the row from `objects` where `id` is 1, I want **one** row with the `id`, `foo`, `bar`, and one list of relations (which should be 2 *and* 3)

Comment: what you want to ends up with? a graph or just a list of Obj and on each one os those Obj, there is a Set of other Obj? i mean, let's say there is only 2 objects on your table, that have a relation. in your main function you create a obj (first) of the first one... if you do first.getOtherObjs().first().getOtherObjs().first(), you want to have a Obj pointing the original one or what?

Comment: Say there are 3 objects with id's 1, 2, 3. 1 is related to 2 and 3 which is registered in the relations table with two rows: one row with `id1 = 1` and `id2 = 2` and one row with `id1 = 3` and `id2` = `1`. Now I want to select the object with id 1 and get the relations with object 2 and 3 in one query. Note that in one relation object 1 is put into `id1` and in the other the object id is registered in `id2`.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  +

Comment: Since the id of the desired object can be either in id1 or id2 in the relations, you have to do two selects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to select all related objects. This can be done as follows:

```
SELECT id1, o1.foo foo1, o1.bar bar1, id2, o2.foo foo2, o2.bar bar2
FROM `relations` r
JOIN `objects` o1 ON o1.id = r.id1
JOIN `objects` o2 ON o2.id = r.id2
```

Comment: Does it matter if I use `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` and whether I add `GROUP BY` or not? I want only one row per object as a final result, with a list of relations added to that row.

Comment: A left join is necessary when the other side may be null. Since id1 and id2 are not null, this is not the case. If you only want the related objects to one object, just add a where clause: WHERE id1 = XXX

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the record that is associated to a specific one `id`, you just need to do:

```
select * 
from objects 
where id in (
    select max(id1, id2) 
    from relations 
    where min(id1, id2)='the desired id'
);
```